# sap.ui.table.Table "VisibleRowCountMode.Auto" mode does not work

Tags: sapui5

I'm having trouble setting the number of rows for a table to automagically fill the available estate of its encapsulating container.

[According to the API](https://sapui5.hana.ondemand.com/sdk/#docs/api/symbols/sap.ui.table.VisibleRowCountMode.html), setting the `visibleRowCountMode` property to `sap.ui.table.VisibleRowCountMode.Auto` should render the table to

> "[...] automatically fills the height of the surrounding container.
>   **The visibleRowCount property is automatically changed accordingly**. All
>   rows need the same height, otherwise the auto mode doesn't always work
>   as expected."

I have used the following code:

```
var oTable = new sap.ui.table.Table( {
    rowHeight           : 30,
    height              : "100%",
    // The below property is seemingly ignored... What did I do wrong?
    visibleRowCountMode : sap.ui.table.VisibleRowCountMode.Auto
});
```

...but as you can see in this jsbin example http://jsbin.com/vazuz/1/edit it just shows the default 10 rows, and certainly doesn't "change the visibleRowCount property accordingly" :-(

Anyone has a solution?
Thanks in advance!

=====================

EDIT: Thanks to @matz3's answer below, I was ultimately able to solve this issue.

Setting the surrounding container DIV to 100%, this seems to be ignored. Setting it to a fixed height, however, worked just fine. But what I really wanted, if a user resized the window, the number of available rows needs to be adjusted accordingly. Setting it to a fixed height is therefor not an option...

However, the trick was in some extra CSS: not only the DIV needed to be set to 100% height, also both BODY and HTML (!!) needed to have a height set to 100%:

```
html, body {
  height: 100%
}

div#uiArea {
  height: 100%
}
```

Now, the table spans the full height of the available viewport, and resizing the window adjusts the table rather nicely. See the final working solution here: http://jsbin.com/bosusuya/3/edit

Matz3, thanks for your help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> [...] automatically fills the height of the surrounding container [...]

Your surrounding container is the view, so you have to set the height of it also to a value (e.g. 100%)

```
this.setHeight("100%");
```

And your view will be set into the uiArea-div, so this one also needs a height (e.g. 500px)

```
<div id="uiArea" style="height:500px"></div>
```

With these changes it now [works as expected](http://jsbin.com/bosusuya/1/edit?html,js,output)

Comment: Ah I see... I was hoping more along the lines of "if I resize my window, the table's visible rowcount is adjusted accordingly"... However, at first it seemed the DIV needs a fixed height since setting it to 100% was not reflected. However, I have found a solution to that as well, I will add it below. But since you steered me towards correct direction to solve my issue, I have marked your question as correct :)

Comment: Yep, just using height="100%" in my mvc:View saves a day, thanks @matz3.

Answer (score 5):

CSS hacks is a dirty way. In my application I use to bind *visibleRowCount* to *Array.length*
For example, if you have model with this data:

```
[{firstName: 'John', lastName: 'Smith',
{firstName: 'David', lastName: 'Ericsson'}]
```

You can bind to *Array* property *length* like this:

```
var oTable = new sap.ui.table.Table({
  visibleRowCount : '{/length}'
})
```

Comment: Hi Nikolay, great answer, and although this wasn't particularly what I'm looking for -- I want the number of rows dependent of my screen height, not the number of items in my model -- but this is certainly helpful in other cases, and thus deserves my upvote :)

Answer (score 1):

I'm with the same issue. I "resolve" that in this manner. This is not perfect, but it's better than UI5 resizing...

```
  _resizeTableRow: function () {

        var oTable = this.getView().byId("referenceTabId");
        var sTop = $('#' + oTable.getId()).offset().top;

        var sHeight = $(document).height();

        //if there a row, you can take the row Height
        //var iRowHeight = $(oTable.getAggregation("rows")[0].getDomRef()).height();

        var iRowHeight = 40; 

        var iRows = Math.trunc((sHeight - sTop ) / iRowHeight);

        oTable.setVisibleRowCount(iRows);
       },
```

Answer (score 0):

Other option is to put the Table in sap.ui.layout.Splitter:

[image: Image of sap.ui.table inside sap.ui.layout.Splitter]